# Removing AlertDialog background

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I have a custom layout in my `AlertDialog` which has a `ListView` inside. Now I want to remove the black background of the `AlertDialog`.

```
           AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            LayoutInflater inflater = this.getLayoutInflater();
            View dialogView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.rate_card_layout, null);
            Button close = (Button) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.btnClose);
            close.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View arg0) {

                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            });


            ListView lv = (ListView)dialogView.findViewById(R.id.listView1);
            RateListAdapter rLAdapter = new RateListAdapter(SActivity.this,
                    listItemsArray);
            lv.setAdapter(rLAdapter);

            builder.setView(dialogView);
            final Dialog dialog = builder.create();

            dialog.show();
```

I tried adding

```
dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(android.graphics.Color.TRANSPARENT));
```

as usual. But that isn't working.

[image]

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: set background in your  rate_card_layout

Comment: try using alpha attribute (not sure though)

Comment: which black background are you refering? can you post an image of what you want.

Comment: @DegenSharew please see attached image

Comment: You are inflating the dialog view from your own xml where is this black background coming? If it is coming from your own xml view you have to change the color there.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
private void updateLayoutParams() {
    Window window = getDialog().getWindow();
    WindowManager.LayoutParams params = window.getAttributes();
    params.dimAmount = 0.2f;

    int margin = getResources().getInteger(R.integer.common_margin);
    DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
    ((WindowManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE)).getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
    params.width = metrics.widthPixels-margin;

    window.setAttributes(params);
    window.setBackgroundDrawableResource(android.R.color.transparent);
    getDialog().setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);

}
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    Log.d(TAG, "onConfigurationChanged");

    updateLayoutParams();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using this to customise your theme.   Also Declare AlertDialogCustom                            iin styles 
`AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(new ContextThemeWrapper(this, R.style.AlertDialogCustom));`

And then style it like you want:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <style name="AlertDialogCustom" parent="@android:style/Theme.Dialog">
        <item name="android:textColor">#00FF00</item>
        <item name="android:typeface">monospace</item>
        <item name="android:textSize">10sp</item>
         ............. //background etc
    </style>
</resources>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This

Add custom dialog style in style.xml

```
 <style name="DialogTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Dialog">
            <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>        
    </style>
```

In Activity

```
Dialog dialog = new Dialog(this, R.style.DialogTheme);
```

OR

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder=new AlertDialog.Builder(this,R.style.DialogTheme);
```